# Core Data: how to reset everything when setup with loadPersistentStores?

Tags: swift, core-data

When using the "new" iOS 10 Core Data setup with `loadPersistentStores`, how can I reset/delete everything? I would like to avoid using the entity names but would love to use something like `destroyPersistentStore`.

I setup my stack the following:

```
persistentContainer = NSPersistentContainer(name: "CoreData", managedObjectModel: mom)
let storeDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
let url = storeDirectory.appendingPathComponent("CoreData.sqlite")
let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: url)
description.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = true
description.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true
persistentContainer.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]

persistentContainer.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (_, error) in
    guard let error = error as NSError? else { return }
    fatalError("Unresolved error: \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
})
persistentContainer.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
persistentContainer.viewContext.undoManager = nil
persistentContainer.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
```

I only found solutions with e.g. BatchDeleteRequests where I need to know all entity names, but I would like something more generic and reset everything - I need the most performant/safest way when the user logs out.

Comment: Does destroyPersistentStoreAtURL(_:withType:options:) help?

Comment: how can I re-setup it after that?

Comment: With [addPersistentStore(ofType:configurationName:at:options:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentstorecoordinator/1468860-addpersistentstore)

Comment: but I'm not doing that the first time, so how should the complete thing look like? Don't know if that's the only/best way...

Answer (score 2):

This suggestion performs the following steps

- Get the store from the `persistentStoreCoordinator`
- Save the URL of the store
- Reset the managed object context
- Destroy the store
- Add a new store

The code assumes the standard implementation of the iOS 10+ `NSPersistentContainer` API with `persistentStoreCoordinator` and `managedObjectContext` properties in AppDelegate and a SQLite store.

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let persistentStoreCoordinator = appDelegate.persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator
let currentStore = persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores.last!
let currentStoreURL = currentStore.url!
appDelegate.managedObjectContext.reset()
do {
    try persistentStoreCoordinator.destroyPersistentStore(at: currentStoreURL, ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType)
    try persistentStoreCoordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: currentStoreURL)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

In iOS I'd recommend to add a new store immediately because normally the application won't terminate and therefore the persistent container won't be recreated.

Comment: unfortunately this does not answer how to reset the stack with the setup from my question...

Comment: Isn't the setup preserved because the coordinator is not recreated? If not, put the code to apply the setup into a method and call this method again after the reset.

Comment: @swalkner Can you clarify what you want that this doesn't do? You mentioned wanting to use `destroyPersistentStore`, which this does.